# Excel sumproudct function in pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

Ok, as a python beginner I found multiplication matrix  in pandas dataframes is very difficult to conduct.

I have two tables look like:

```
  df1 

      Id    lifetime    0    1    2    3    4    5  .... 30 
  0    1      4        0.1   0.2  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.4...  0.2
  1    2      7        0.3   0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5  0.4...  0.2
  2    3      8        0.5   0.2  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.4...  0.6
   .......
  9    6      10       0.3   0.2  0.5  0.4  0.5  0.4...  0.2

  df2 

     Group lifetime      0    1    2    3    4    5  .... 30 
  0    2      4        0.9   0.8  0.9  0.8  0.8  0.8...  0.9
  1    2      7        0.8   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.8  0.8...  0.9
  2    3      8        0.9   0.7  0.8  0.8  0.9  0.9...  0.9
   .......
  9    5      10       0.8   0.9  0.7  0.7  0.9  0.7...  0.9
```

I want to perform excel's sumproduct function in my codes and the length of the columns that need to be summed are based on the lifetime in column 1 of both dfs, e,g.,

```
 for row 0 in df1&df2, lifetime=4:
 sumproduct(df1 row 0  from column 0 to column 3,
            df2 row 0 from column 0 to column 3)

  for row 1 in df1&df2, lifetime=7
  sumproduct(df1 row 2 from column 0 to column 6,
             df2 row 2 from column 0 to column 6)

  .......
```

How can I do this?

Comment: whats your intended output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .iloc to access row and columns with integers.
So where lifetime==4 is row 0, and if you count the column numbers where Id is zero, then column labeled as 0 would be 2, and column labeled as 3 would be 5, to get that interval you would enter 2:6.
Once you get the correct data in both data frames with *.iloc[0,2:6]*, you run np.dot
See below:

```
import numpy as np
np.dot(df1.iloc[0,2:6], df2.iloc[1,2:6])
```

Just to make sure you have the right data, try just running

```
df1.iloc[0,2:6]
```

Then try the np.dot product. You can read up on "pandas iloc" and "slicing" for more info.